# vuex computed properties are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuex

test.vue, the 'test' property is reactive in vue component, but 'title' property from vuex store is not reactive when I changing the value of the first input tag. I found some similar questions but the solutions are not work for me. where did I do wrong here?

**template**

```
<div class="title">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="palceholder" 
    v-model="title"
   />
</div>
<input v-model="test"/>
<div>{{test}}</div>
<div>
  {{title}}
</div>
```

**js**

```
data() {
  test: 'test'
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['article']),
  title: {
    get () { 
       return this.article.title || '' 
    },
    set (value) { this.$store.commit(Types.UPDATE_TITLE, value) }
  }
}
```

**store.js**

```
import * as Types from '../mutation-types'
import Vue from 'vue'
const state = {
  article: {}
}

const getters = {
  article: state => state.article
}

const mutations = {
  [Types.UPDATE_TITLE] (state, title) {
    state.article = { ...state.article, title }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working, meaning the issue is being caused by something other than what you've shared. https://jsfiddle.net/r3aty4co/

Comment: @thanksd, thanks a lot! I'll check out my files again.